# Lasso, Ridge and Best Subset estimator for orthogonal cases

Tags: regression, lasso, ridge-regression, estimators, regularization

I am reading the book "Elements of Statistical Learning". In the book the author compares the OSL estimator with Lasso, Ridge and Best Subset for the special case of Orthogonal X. I am attaching the particular estimator. I am able to derive the estimator for Ridge but am finding it hard to solve for Best Subset and Lasso. How exactly do they arrive at the final formula?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the context, I'm assuming that the $\beta_j's$ are the regular least squares estimates, and the table is showing how they would be transformed under each of the listed methods.

**Best Subset**:

Because the columns are orthonormal, the least squares coefficients are simply $\hat{B_j} = {x_j^{T}y}$.  (Orthogonality implies that they're given by $\hat{B_j} = {\frac{x_j^{T}y}{x_j^{T}x_j}}$, but since we have ortho*normal* columns, ${x_j^{T}x_j}$ = 1.)

Then by definition of best subset, we're looking for the $M$ predictors that gives the smalles residual sum of squares.  This is equivalent to finding the $M$ *largest* (in absolute value) coefficients.  This might already be intuitive, but if not, note that the residual sum of squares from regressing ${y}$ on ${x_j}$ is given by:

$r_j = (y - x_j\hat{\beta_j})^T(y - x_j\hat{\beta_j})$

$= y^Ty - 2\hat{\beta_j}x_j^Ty + \hat{{\beta_j}}^2$

$= y^Ty - 2(x_j^Ty)^2 + (x_j^Ty)^2$ (applying the solution of $\hat{B_j} = {x_j^{T}y}$)

$= y^Ty-(x_j^Ty)^2$

$= y^Ty - {|\hat{B_j}|}^2$

Which is clearly minimized by having $|\hat{B_j}|$ as large as possible.

It follows then that the solution for best subset with $M$ predictors is to regress $y$ on each $x_j$, order the coefficients by size in absolute value, and then choose the $M$ largest of them, which is what is given by the solution in the table.

**Lasso**:

The lasso coefficient for regressing $y$ on $x_j$ is finding the $\hat{\beta}$ that minimizes $\frac{1}{2}(y - x_j\hat{\beta})^T(y - x_j\hat{\beta}) + \lambda|\hat{\beta}|$.  Now assume that $\hat{\beta} \neq 0$.  Taking the derivative of that expression with respect to $\hat{\beta}$ and setting equal to 0 gives

$-x_j^T(y - x_j\hat{\beta}) + sign(\hat{\beta})\lambda = 0$, where we need the sign operator because the derivative of $|\hat{\beta}|$ is $1$ if $\hat{\beta}$ > 0 and $-1$ otherwise.

Simplifying the expression above gives

$-x_j^Ty + x_j^Tx_j\hat{\beta} + sign(\hat{\beta})\lambda = 0$

$\implies \hat{\beta} = x_j^Ty - sign(\hat{\beta})\lambda$ (where we used the fact that $x_j^Tx_j = 1$, since the columns are orthonormal.

$\implies \hat{\beta} = \hat{\beta_j} - sign(\hat{\beta})\lambda$ (recall the definition of $\hat{\beta_j}$, the least squares solution).

Now we consider cases for the sign of $\hat{\beta}$:

1. If $sign(\hat{\beta}) > 0$, then we must have $\hat{\beta_j} - \lambda > 0$, which means $\hat{\beta_j} > \lambda$ (and therefore $\hat{\beta_j} > 0)$.

- Note that if this is the case, then the lasso estimate is given by $\hat{\beta} = \hat{\beta_j} - \lambda = \hat{\beta_j} - \lambda = sign(\hat{\beta_j})(|\hat{\beta_j}| - \lambda)$

2. If $sign(\hat{\beta}) < 0$, then we must have $\hat{\beta_j} + \lambda < 0$, which means $-\hat{\beta_j} >\lambda$ (and therefore $\hat{\beta_j} < 0)$.

- Note that if this is the case, then the lasso estimate is given by $\hat{\beta} = \hat{\beta_j} + \lambda = -|\hat{\beta_j}| + \lambda = sign(\hat{\beta_j})(|\hat{\beta_j}| - \lambda)$

In each of these, we required that $|\hat{\beta_j}| > \lambda$.  If that was wrong, or our initial assumption that $\hat{\beta} \neq 0$ must have been wrong and we have $\hat{\beta} = 0$, which means we can say that we only take the positive part ($(|\hat{\beta_j}| - \lambda)_+$) in each of the solutions since otherwise $\hat{\beta} = 0$.

Therefore, you get the solution in the table.